# How to convert a pull-request to draft with github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to convert a pull-request back to a draft,
using github actions and gh.

But my action always fails when converting an open PR back to draft, with the log:

`API call failed: GraphQL: github-actions[bot] does not have permission to convert the pull request PR_somenumbers to draft. (convertPullRequestToDraft)`

Info:
*At the time writing this question, GitHub faced an outage.
I tested again now one day later and the error still exists.
So it is **not** related to the GitHub outage.*

My actions looks (trimmed) like so:

1. On a new opened pull request do:
2. checkout the repo
3. Get the base branch of this pull request
4. Search for open pull-requests, that have this base branch from 3. as head
5. Iterate through the open pull-requests from 4. and if the base of this PR is my main branch, then:
6. Set the PR status to 'draft' <- This is not working

```
    name: Bot
    on:
      pull_request:
        types:
          - opened
    jobs:
      comment:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            MAIN_BRANCH_NAME: 'main'
            BASE_PR_REF: ${{ github.base_ref }}
        steps:
          - name: Check out repository code
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
            with:
              ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
          - run: |
              for base_pr_id in $(gh pr list --search "head:${{ env.BASE_PR_REF }}" --json number --jq '.[].number'); do 
                  if [ ${{ env.MAIN_BRANCH_NAME }} == $( gh pr view $base_pr_id --json baseRefName  --jq '.baseRefName') ]; then
                      gh pr ready $base_pr_id --undo <-- This won't work
                  fi
                  
              done
```

I also tried to add specific permissions, but none of them worked:

```
    permissions: 
        pull-requests: write
        contents: write
        statuses: write
```

I also gave the actions read and write permissions in GitHub Settings.
No success. Any idea is highly welcome.

Comment: GitHub appears to be fully-operational again. Give this another try.

Comment: Tried again. Still not working and I still face the permission error. It's not related to the outage.

Comment: Sorry if this comment appears stupid, but just asking for completeness: The Github account in question allows all (incl. private ones) and specifically this one (is it public?) repository to have pull requests with draft status?

Comment: @hakre No way. I'm really uncomfortable with this, but of course I tested my action in a private repository first. Working all the time in public or company repos, I wasn't aware that private repos (not company) don't support drafts as a feature. And guess what, I changed it to be public and now it works. So this was absolutely no stupid question. I feel very dumb now. 
Please add this as an answer and since it solves my problem, I'll mark this as the solving answer. For further readers: https://github.com/pricing (scroll all the way down to code workflow).

Comment: @JacksOnF1re: Okay, that was exactly the reason why I was asking as I've been there (just not via the API) so reminded me that there may be actually no access rights. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every pull request on Github can be changed to a draft. For example free accounts on private repositories don't have the option to put a pull request into draft status.

So *if* that is the case (private repository which does not allow drafts on pull requests), consider to upgrade the account or first of all create a public test repository for sandboxing as public repositories should allow draft status on pull requests.

This is easy to forget once the draft option is considered to be available.

Quoting [from the  OPs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175367/how-to-convert-a-pull-request-to-draft-with-github-action/76213345#comment134391896_76175367), user [JacksOnF1re](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2607567/jacksonf1re), who confirms the educated guess:

> [...] I wasn't aware that private repos (not company) don't support drafts as a feature. And guess what, I changed it to be public and now it works. [...]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this workflow with a **p**ersonal **a**ccess **t**oken? It seems that the default user that is used by GitHub Actions does not have permission to do this conversation.

You can create a PAT [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens), store it in your repository secrets, and use it like so:

```
    comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_PAT }}
        MAIN_BRANCH_NAME: 'main'
        BASE_PR_REF: ${{ github.base_ref }}
```

You can read [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#granting-additional-permissions) more about what to do if you need a token that requires permissions that aren't available in the GITHUB_TOKEN.

Comment: Why does it seem so (own testing? documenation?)? Please provide reference for the answer so it sounds less speculative.

Comment: @hakre, look at the question, they have included the error message they received: "API call failed: GraphQL: github-actions[bot] does not have permission to convert the pull request PR_somenumbers to draft. (convertPullRequestToDraft)."

From my own experience, the default GitHub actions user can't do some actions, such as merging PRs in some cases - so I also had to use a PAT for some PR-related workflows. I've edited my comment to include a link to the official documentation.